# IllegalStateException Cannot start this animator on a detached view

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to troubleshoot a crash reported by Crashlytics for an Android app. According to Crashlytics, the crash only occurs on Android OS 8.1, not on any other OS versions.

The problem is that the stack trace from Crashlytics does not give me any clue at all about where / how the crash occurred, as it only shows the Android SDK call stack. Here is the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view!
at android.view.RenderNode.addAnimator(RenderNode.java:799)
at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:299)
at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:289)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleComponent$RenderNodeAnimatorSet.start(RippleComponent.java:316)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleComponent.startPendingAnimation(RippleComponent.java:200)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleComponent.draw(RippleComponent.java:167)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.drawBackgroundAndRipples(RippleDrawable.java:892)
at android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable.draw(RippleDrawable.java:699)
at android.view.View.onDrawForeground(View.java:20914)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19205)
at android.transition.TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap(TransitionUtils.java:177)
at android.app.SharedElementCallback.onCaptureSharedElementSnapshot(SharedElementCallback.java:205)
at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.captureSharedElementState(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:810)
at android.app.ActivityTransitionCoordinator.captureSharedElementState(ActivityTransitionCoordinator.java:733)
at android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator.sharedElementTransitionComplete(ExitTransitionCoordinator.java:405)
at android.app.ExitTransitionCoordinator$9.onTransitionEnd(ExitTransitionCoordinator.java:362)
at android.transition.Transition.end(Transition.java:1926)
at android.transition.TransitionSet$TransitionSetListener.onTransitionEnd(TransitionSet.java:369)
at android.transition.Transition.end(Transition.java:1926)
at android.transition.TransitionSet$TransitionSetListener.onTransitionEnd(TransitionSet.java:369)
at android.transition.Transition.end(Transition.java:1926)
at android.transition.TransitionSet$TransitionSetListener.onTransitionEnd(TransitionSet.java:369)
at android.transition.Transition.end(Transition.java:1926)
at android.transition.Transition.runAnimators(Transition.java:883)
at android.transition.TransitionSet.runAnimators(TransitionSet.java:433)
at android.transition.TransitionSet.runAnimators(TransitionSet.java:433)
at android.transition.TransitionSet.runAnimators(TransitionSet.java:433)
at android.transition.TransitionSet.runAnimators(TransitionSet.java:433)
at android.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1780)
at android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:315)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:977)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2349)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I searched Stackoverflow as well as other sites about "Cannot start this animator on a detached view", but all involves their own custom class being called. However, in my case, it seems that Android SDK itself crashed!

Anybody had similar experience before? Does the stack trace tell anything at all? Where should I start to look into the problem? Activity transition? Animation code?

Any helps are greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wish that this helps you: https://www.reddit.com/r/redditsync/comments/7c0k9m/bug_animation_related_crashes/

Comment: are you using `MaterialShowCaseView`?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but for others facing this problem, I have this problem too.
I'm using [`MaterialShowcaseView`](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) and the problem is when a user opens an activity and a `showCase` want to appeared, if user closes current activity immediately, that activity will detaches all layout widgets. So reveal animation cant starts because the view doesn't exists anymore! This is an [open issue in github](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView/issues/145).